# How do I test a polling react hook using Jest with mock timers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a polling hook which appears to be working in my app.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
/**
 * @param asyncFunction
 * @param interval milliseconds between calls to the asyncFunction, defaults to a minute
 * @param immediate if true it will run the asyncFunction immediately before looping
 */
export function usePolling(
  asyncFunction: () => any | PromiseLike<any>,
  interval = 60000,
  immediate = true
) {
  const timeoutRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>();
  const mountedRef = useRef(false);
  const activeRef = useRef(false);

  const wrappedAsyncFunction = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log("POLL", { mountedRef, activeRef });
    if (!mountedRef.current || activeRef.current) {
      // don't process if currently active or the component is unmounted
      return;
    }
    activeRef.current = true;
    try {
      console.log("ABOUT TO ASYNC", { mountedRef, activeRef });
      await asyncFunction();
      console.log("ASYNC DONE", { mountedRef, activeRef });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error while polling", e);
    }
    console.log("ABOUT TO SET TIMEOUT");
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(wrappedAsyncFunction, interval);
    console.log(" SET TIMEOUT", timeoutRef);
    activeRef.current = false;
  }, [mountedRef.current, activeRef.current, asyncFunction, interval]);

  useEffect(() => {
    mountedRef.current = true;
    if (immediate) {
      wrappedAsyncFunction();
    } else {
      timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(wrappedAsyncFunction, interval);
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current!);
      mountedRef.current = false;
      activeRef.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return { activeRef };
}
```

And my test looks like this

```
  it("should work with just the callback", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const callback = jest.fn();
    let renderCount = 0;
    function MyComponent() {
      usePolling(callback);
      ++renderCount;
      return (<div data-testid="test">{renderCount}</div>);
    }

    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />)
    expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("1");
    expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
    jest.runAllTicks();
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    console.log("ABOUT TO RUN ALL TIMERS")
    jest.runAllTimers();
    console.log("RAN ALL TIMERS")
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(2);
      expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
    });
    jest.runAllTimers();
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(3);
      expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
    });
  })
```

I am making a few assertions

1. that the callback is called once before any timeouts (since it's `immediate = true` by default)
2. that every time the runAllTimers() is called, the callback is called.
3. that there's no re-render since I am not updating any state

Without the mock timers it appears to work

```
  it("should work with a real clock", async () => {
    const callback = jest.fn();
    let renderCount = 0;
    function MyComponent() {
      usePolling(callback, 500, true);
      ++renderCount;
      return (<div data-testid="test">{renderCount}</div>);
    }

    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />)
    expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("1");
    expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(2);
      expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
    });
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(3);
      expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
    });
  })
```

I have tried doing the following as well with no luck...

```
...
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    jest.runAllTimers();
    jest.runAllTicks();
    jest.runAllImmediates();
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(2); // fails here
      expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
    });
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently though not exactly sure why... I need to waitFor the first one as well.  Even if it set it correctly without the `waitFor`

```
  it("should work with just the callback", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const callback = jest.fn();
    let renderCount = 0;
    function MyComponent() {
      usePolling(callback);
      ++renderCount;
      return (<div data-testid="test">{renderCount}</div>);
    }

    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />)
    expect(getByTestId("test").textContent).toEqual("1");
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
      expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
    jest.runAllTimers();
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
      expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(2);
    });
    jest.runAllTimers();
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(renderCount).toEqual(1);
      expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(3);
    });
  })
```